# Graficas con php y MySql

Tags: php, html, css3, mysqli, programación-funcional

Hoal amigo.
Tengo una inconsistencia con este trabajo pero no logro identificar el error.
debo graficar en barras la cantidad de alumnos que existe por comuna de a cuerdo al grado que yo seleccione. en estos momentos me sale la grafica pero todas las barras de un mismo tamaño y por consola no me aparece ningun error. El select me permite seleccionar un grado lo cual los valores los traigo de acuerdo a un for este va desde el primer grado hasa el ultimo, al seleccionar un grado me debe mostrar en el plano cartesioano las barras correspondientes a las comunas donde de donde pertenecen los alumnos y teniendo en cuenta su cantidad, si en alguna comuna no hay alumnos pues no se debe mostrar la barra.

Este es el codigo index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Estadistica</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chartJS/Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
        .caja{
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 250px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
        }
        .caja select{
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .resultados{
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 40px;
            width: 1000px;
        }
    </style>
    <body> 
        <div class="caja">
            <select onChange="mostrarResultados(this.value);">
                <?php
                    for($i=701;$i<1109;$i++){
                        if($i == 701){
                            echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$i.'</option>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="resultados"><canvas id="grafico"></canvas></div>
    </body>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(mostrarResultados(701));  
                function mostrarResultados(year){
                    $('.resultados').html('<canvas id="grafico"></canvas>');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'php/procesar.php',
                        data: 'year='+year,
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success:function(response){

                            var valores = response;

                            var p = valores[0];
                            var s = valores[1]

                            var Datos = {
                                    labels : ['Comuna 1', 'Comuna 2', 'Comuna 3', 'Comuna 4', 'Comuna 5', 'Comuna 6', 'Comuna 7', 'Nulos'],
                                    datasets : [
                                        {
                                            fillColor : 'rgba(91,228,146,0.6)', //COLOR DE LAS BARRAS
                                            strokeColor : 'rgba(57,194,112,0.7)', //COLOR DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                            highlightFill : 'rgba(73,206,180,0.6)', //COLOR "HOVER" DE LAS BARRAS
                                            highlightStroke : 'rgba(66,196,157,0.7)', //COLOR "HOVER" DEL BORDE DE LAS BARRAS
                                            data : response
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            var contexto = document.getElementById('grafico').getContext('2d');
                            window.Barra = new Chart(contexto).Bar(Datos, { responsive : true });
                            Barra.clear();
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
    </script>
</html>
```

Este el código procesar.php

```
<?php
    include_once('conexion.php');
    class Procesar extends Model{

        public function __construct(){ 
            parent::__construct(); 
        }

        public function build_report($year){
            $total = array();
            for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){
                $comuna = $i+1;
                $uno = $this->db->query("SELECT count(cantidad) AS total FROM tbl_consulta1 WHERE grado = '$year' AND comuna='UNO'");
                $dos = $this->db->query("SELECT count(cantidad) AS total FROM tbl_consulta1 WHERE grado = '$year' AND comuna='DOS'");



                $total[$i] = 0;
                $total[$i] = 1;
                $total[$i] = 2;
                $total[$i] = 3;
                $total[$i] = 4;
                $total[$i] = 5;
                $total[$i] = 6;
                //foreach ($sql as $key){ 
                    //$total[$i] = ($key['total'] == null)? 0 : $key['total']; }
            }            
            return $total;
        }

    }

    if($_POST['year']){
        $class = new Procesar;
        $run = $class->build_report($_POST['year']);
        exit(json_encode($run));
    }
?>
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Agregando console.log(response), me aparece lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que te aparece cuando haces `console.log(response):`

Comment: Hola, donde puedo hacer esta prueba por favor.

Comment: Despues de hacer una busqueda encuentro lo siguiente:Chart.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null
    at s.getMaximumWidth (Chart.min.js:10)
    at s.resize (Chart.min.js:10)
    at Chart.min.js:10
    at s.each (Chart.min.js:10)
    at Chart.min.js:10

Comment: Debajo de success:function(response){    pon console.log(response)  y pon lo que tienes de respuesta

Comment: Hola, he realizado lo que me dices y me aparece en consola lossiguiente:(8) ["55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55"]
0: "55"
1: "55"
2: "55"
3: "55"
4: "55"
5: "55"
6: "55"
7: "55"
length: 8